# Google Apps "Unknown macro doGet"

Tags: templates, google-apps-script

Every time a deploy the exercise from "Pulling data into a template" from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service I get the message "Unknown macro doGet"

There is no function (macro) doGet in this exercise.  There was on the PRIOR exercise "Pulling data into a template"

The function on this exercise is:

function getData() {
return SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileID').getRangeByName('dataRange').getValues();
}

But every time I deploy it says "Unknown Macro doGet"

Why is this script still looking back at the prior doGet, in another script?  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a full sample script. It's just an embellishment on the previous script. You still need a doGet in every HtmlService app, and the one from the previous example is supposed to be part of the script you use here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cory G.  So you must also have a .gs that contains this code.

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myTemplate').evaluate();
}
```